# problem with validating form in spring under hibernate validator

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

i have a problem with a simple form in spring that use validating with hibenate validator
my form:

```
 <form:form method="POST" commandName="info">

     username:<form:input path="username"/> <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
     password:<form:password path="password"/><form:errors path="password"></form:errors> 
     <input type="submit" value="add new writer">
  </form:form>
```

my controller for form:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value={"/createnewuser"})
public String showCreateNewUserFrom( @javax.validation.Valid   Information info,Model model,BindingResult br)
{
    //System.out.println("hello post");
    if(br.hasErrors())
    {

        return "admin/createuserform";
    }
    else
    return "admin/createuserform";
}
```

my problem is when my form is invalide that throw exception!!i want jsp view of errors

```
org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'information' on field 'username': rejected value [vc]; codes [Size.information.username,Size.username,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [information.username,username]; arguments []; default message [username],10,4]; default message [username must be at least 4 and at most 10 character]
Field error in object 'information' on field 'password': rejected value [fg]; codes [Size.information.password,Size.password,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [information.password,password]; arguments []; default message [password],8,5]; default message [username must be at least 5 and at most 8 character]
```

i will be realy greatfull for anyhelp

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments):

> The Errors or BindingResult parameters have to follow the model object that is being bound immediately as the method signature might have more that one model object and Spring will create a separate BindingResult instance for each of them [...] To get this working you have to reorder the parameters [...]

Looks like your case..